# SQL Server : update a table with values from same table based on IDs in a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called `STOCK` that I want to update that looks like this:

```
-------------------------
NUMBER           | UNITS
-------------------------
NA13ALPK1010     |  9
NA13ALANA1010    | 11
NA13ALPK1065     |  4
NA13ALANA106     |  5
ON0003    XS     |  1
AT3322    2      |  3
```

Based on a second table called `PKGINV` that looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------
PKGNUMBER        | BOARDNUMBER
----------------------------------------
NA13ALPK1010   | NA13ALANA1010
NA13ALPK1065   | NA13ALANA106
```

First, I'd like to be able to do a `SELECT` with some type of join so that I can show `UNITS` from `STOCK` for both `PKGNUMBER` and `BOARDNUMBER` in `PKGINV`.

Then, I'd like to update `UNITS` in `STOCK` when `PKGINV.PKGNUMBER = STOCK.NUMBER` with the `PKGINV.BOARDNUMBER UNITS` from `STOCK`.

So after the update, `NA13ALPK1010` would have `UNITS` of `11` (the `UNITS` from `NA13ALANA1010`) and `NA13ALPK1065` would have `UNITS` of `5` (the `UNITS` from `NA13ALANA106`).

Thanks in advance for your help on this!

Comment: I understand your need with the `SELECT` query, but not your need to update. What is the business rule you want to apply here? What is the reason of your update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SELECT is simply a matter of joining the STOCK table twice:

```
SELECT 
PKGNUMBER_Stock.UNITS AS PKGNUMBER_UNITS
,BOARDNUMBER_Stock.UNITS AS BOARDNUMBER_UNITS
FROM 
PKGINV AS pkginv
JOIN STOCK AS PKGNUMBER_Stock ON PKGNUMBER_Stock.NUMBER = pkginv.PKGNUMBER
JOIN STOCK AS BOARDNUMBER_Stock ON BOARDNUMBER_Stock.NUMBER = pkginv.BOARDNUMBER
```

Likewise, the UPDATE statement should simply match the join set above:

```
UPDATE PKGNUMBER_Stock
SET PKGNUMBER_Stock.UNITS = BOARDNUMBER_Stock.UNITS
FROM 
PKGINV AS pkginv
JOIN STOCK AS PKGNUMBER_Stock ON PKGNUMBER_Stock.NUMBER = pkginv.PKGNUMBER
JOIN STOCK AS BOARDNUMBER_Stock ON BOARDNUMBER_Stock.NUMBER = pkginv.BOARDNUMBER
```

Comment: thank you.  I accepted this answer as the most thorough, although the first answer above addressed the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `Stock` to `PKGINV` two times:

```
Update s
set s.UNITS = s2.UNITS 
from STOCK s
join PKGINV p on s.NUMBER = p.PKGNUMBER
join STOCK s2 on p.BOARDNUMBER = s2.NUMBER
```